# Reading emails from IMAP - how to flag them as SEEN when processed?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm reading and processing emails received from IMAP using JODD mail library. API is very nice but I struggle with one logical issue. I'm using code as following:

```
EmailFilter filter= new EmailFilter();
filter.flag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, false);
session.receiveEmailAndMarkSeen(filter);
```

By calling `session.receiveEmailAndMarkSeen` I receive all unread emails and these are marked as read immediately. Now when processing fails in my code for any reason, and I try to receive emails again all these unprocessed emails are marked as read already and not downloaded anymore. I would rather download emails and mark them as read individualy as beeing processed successfully.

So I tried to receive them with `session.receiveEmail` but not sure how to mark them as read when processed? Any hint how to do it? I can see that email object has 'flag' property I can set but not sure how to send this information back to server.

Comment: quick idea: 1) download emails as non-read 2) after processing, just download email(s) again as Seen? meanwhile, will check if this is possible in java mail api.

Comment: If you solve your own problem, then post your solution as an answer (and accept it after the timeout). Don't add the solution to the question itself: that is not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize possible solutions:

1. Re-fetch email with `Seen` flag. The downside is that email is fetched again.
2. What you wrote - using a `Session` and a `Folder`.
3. Finally - starting from the next version of Jodd, you will have the method `updateEmailFlags` that would give you options to just call it:

   mymail.flags(newFlags);
   ReceiveMailSession.updateEmailFlags(mymail);

The result would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** I'm creating connection manualy using common JAVA mail classes - Session and Store.

```
Session sess = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = sess.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imapServerHost", "username","password");
```

... then I create folder object (points to Inbox)

```
Folder folder = store.getFolder(this.imapFolder);
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

... then I receive emails using session and store

```
ReceiveMailSession session=new ReceiveMailSession(sess, store);
```

... after email processed, I send back SEEN=true message using folder object.

```
Flags f=new Flags();
f.add(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
folder.setFlags(new int[] {email.getMessageNumber()}, f,true);
```